# Optaplanner - hangs on custom step

Tags: optaplanner

I am implementing a custom move and optaplanner is stuck on some step. After the end of the time, the last step is logged:

LS step (2221), time spent (2575148), score (-5029504hard/0medium/0soft), new best score (-5029504hard/0medium/0soft), accepted/selected move count (20/109451), picked move..

Why is the number of selected so large? My custom factory moves don't generate that many moves per step. Also i have other move types in UnionSelector and they are large size. Why are they not accepted? I suspect my custom move has a bug and it has something to do with the multi-threaded solution.

Comment: I suspect it may be related to https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1180?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel . My problem is solved if I don't add moves that return isMoveDoable=false to the custom move factory. But I don't fully understand why it helps.

Comment: You are correct. Feel free to answer your own question, as you figured it out on your own.